# How can I localize ToolTipService.ToolTip in WinUI3

Tags: localization, tooltip, winui-3

I have create a control in WinUI3. Then, I give this control a UID(teachingTip) and write `teachingTip.ToolTipService.Tooltip`and the sentences in .resw file. When I launch the app and place the mouse over the control, but nothing happened. I only find one document and change`teachingTip.ToolTipService.Tooltip`to`teachingTip.[using:Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls]ToolTipService.Tooltip`. However,it doesn't work either.

Anyone could please help me to make the control's Tooltip display the sentence in .resw file? I'm new to WinUI and I'm not so good at English, so if there are any technological or linguistic mistake, please add a commit to let me know about it.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls namespace is UWP. WinUI3 namespace is Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.tooltipservice

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Follow your advice, I have changed Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls to Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls. But it didn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your control,

```xml
<local:SomeControl x:Uid="LocalizedSomeControl" />
```

then in *Resources.resw*,

| Name | Value |
| --- | --- |
| LocalizedSomeControl.ToolTipService.ToolTip | This is the localized tooltip. |

Comment: It didn't work either. By the way, I'm using WinUI3Localizer

Comment: Thanks for using the WinUI3Localizer. Unfortunately, the WinUI3Localizer is failing to localize this case. I created an [issue](https://github.com/AndrewKeepCoding/WinUI3Localizer/issues/36) on the GitHub repo.

Comment: The problem was that WinUI3Localizer doesn't support localization for attached properties, `ToolTipService.ToolTip` in this case. I think I can make time to add this feature this weekend.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will waiting for it.

Comment: Just shipped WinUI3Localizer v2.1.0. Let me know if you have any feedback.

Comment: It works well after updating. Thanks for your help.